# Can the Facebook Marketing API return a list of objects that represent each individual click on an ad, including the FBCLID and spend for each click?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights, facebook-business-sdk

So far I've been able to get an overview of the total number of clicks during a specified time period using the Insights API:

```
{"impressions":"5547","spend":"160.53","clicks":"206","date_start":"2022-06-08","date_stop":"2022-06-08"}
```

What I would like instead is a list of objects that represent each individual click during that period, with fields like "fbclid", "date", "spend", etc:

```
{"fbclid":"jg4k0tkladskds08kds","spend":"0.75", "date":"2022-06-08 12:24:15"}
{"fbclid":"098okjfesdjflsdjffd","spend":"0.72", "date":"2022-06-08 18:36:02"}
{"fbclid":"04538hjfldkjlkdjfdfsdf","spend":"0.67", "date":"2022-06-08 21:12:12"}
etc...
```

Is this possible with either the Insights API or something else within the Marketing API? I'm using the Facebook Business SDK for PHP in case that's relevant. Thanks!